# Ubuntu Server : extra drivers during install

Tags: installation, drivers, 13.04, server, lan

is there a way when installing Ubuntu Server (13.04) to activate linux-image-extra.
My LAN card has his driver in that extra package and as is it not used at install, the installer can't see my card.
(for information my driver is jme)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use the package in Live Ubuntu you use **during** the installation or the one you actually **install** ?
For the first, just press Ctrl-Alt-T to get to Console and do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install whatever
```

For the second, complete the installation procedure. However, when installer prompts you to do the reboot, don't. Instead, [use this instruction](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1156240) to get into you fresh ubuntu without reboot, and do the above commands there. 
Finally, if you don't have Internet access during installation, just download the package [from here](http://packages.ubuntu.com). Put it somewhere you can reach during installation. Use

```
sudo dpkg -i package.deb
```

to install it.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell that when you are in the installer of the Ubuntu Server distribution, you don't have access to apt-get nor dpkg (that's in fact the problem).